# Ember-cli Node.js - Using Neat and Bourbon

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-cli, bourbon, neat

I'm not sure the correct way to include 'Neat' in an ember-cli application.

I installed Bourbon using the ember-cli-bourbon addon, and then just @import "bourbon" in my scss file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to install neat via bower:

```
bower install neat --save
```

Then in your scss file, after you import bourbon:

```
@import 'bourbon';
@import 'bower_components/neat/app/assets/stylesheets/neat';
```

Comment: So I would just create a Brocfile in the root directory of the neat node module? Sorry if that's a dumb question - first experience with ember-cli.

Comment: @Joel sorry, my original answer is what I use with less, and was optional. You should be able to just link directly to it in your scss file.

Comment: I'm actually using the ember-cli broccoli version of SASS. Link what part of the module directly?

In the scss file, if I use @import 'neat' I get:  

 file to import not found or unreadable:

Comment: Never mind, I didn't realize you updated the answer. It worked, thanks a lot!